# Watch OS and OS2 differences in Images.xcassets and WatchKit Extension?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2

I have a working app for Watch OS which uses the following code to set the background of a group, the images are located in Images.xcassets in the WatchKit:

```
scalaImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"scalaMHR%d", imageNumber];
[self.mainGroup setBackgroundImageNamed:scalaImageName];
```

If I run the app under watch OS2 I get the error message: **MyApp WatchKit Extension[325:28425] Unable to find image named "scalaMHR1" on Watch**

Are there any changes in watch OS2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. I found out the problem is OS2 actually searches the @2x images instead. So you can just move the x1 images to x2 in the asset folder. It will work.